# What's a practical use for a gravity based magic system?

Tags: science-based, magic, physics, space, space-travel

My magic system operates thusly -

Using some kind of material, probably a special clay, maybe it's been changed by some kind of process, a magic user can shape the clay into balls of varying sizes, and then use them to make gravitational systems - they'd make a fixed point as a "star," then add onto it by putting other clay pellets around the main body in different orbits.

This is in the context of a fantasy world that is on the cusp of the space age, and the people in this world are racing to build rockets because they believe the magic system will be more powerful in space, or will be enhanced by material from moons and asteroids.

So I know that I have this vaguely defined, but can y'all think of any practical uses for this magic system?

Comment: There are several "gravity magic" questions already have you looked at them? Unfortunately at the moment this question is too vague for me to understand what you actually want to know, it may even be duplicating existing work but I just can't tell.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as it recently got brought to the front page. As written this looks like a request for idea generation and brainstorming rather than a specific question about building a fictional world.

Comment: @Pelinore gosh, you again. Yeah, this was a stupid question. I hate that I can't just delete stuff here. I have to endure people telling me i was stupid over and over again.

Comment: Yeah the deleting stuff becomes impossible as soon as someone posts an answer I think, been caught by it myself, there, deleted my comment, you read it already after all.

Comment: I flagged the question to be closed by mods, that's the best I can do at the moment

Answer (score 0):

The first uses that come to mind would just basically be to use the clay to make models and simulations to better understand gravity and the solar system and stuff. Uses outside of that requires interpretations of the limits of the system.

Assuming that the gravity from the clay and star only influences only the clay, and if the magic person can choose anywhere within sight to place the ‘star’ and isn’t restricted to decide how much simulated mass the sun or point has, then you could easily weaponize the clay by filling an object with clay and choosing a target to be the star and make its mass absurdly high so the clay moves the object rapidly towards the target. If the magic person can move the ‘star’ while still influencing the clay then they can have remote control projectiles. On the defensive side, if a person can give their stars negative mass and influence other people’s clay then they could try to create an anti gravity repulsion field by making a star in front of them with negative mass. And if negative mass is out of the question they could try to steer the incoming clay away by making their ‘star’ away from them. If some people can make more massive stars than others, the winner would be the one with the most massive star or the one with the more clever use of gravity.

Non combat uses following the same rules as above could consist of clay driven hovercraft or cars which use the gravity influence from the star to pull clay contained in the vehicle.

As long as you have clay and a strong enough star you could push or pull anything, as long as the clay could be stuck onto or into it. You could replicate the Force from Star Wars although it would take a lot of practice and skill to truly master.

Answer (score 0):

## Using Goliath to move David:

If I'm following your system, you create a sort of artificial gravity in simulations of miniature solar systems. So if this is how your magic system works, can't you use it to create a simulated solar system with one of the "planet" nodes as a ship? This would allow your ship to essentially undergo a [slingshot effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_assist) while still on the planet. If these solar systems defy conventional gravity, the bodies involved are able to overcome the effects of gravity. And if the effect can be switched on and off, then the two nodes (if the "sun" node has to be a physical object, then possibly with it on a long tether) could essentially repeat-slingshot your ship into orbit, then through space.

**I'm assuming your magic system doesn't allow a straight-up gravity drive where you eternally fall towards your "sun" that is perpetually positioned always a bit ahead of the ship.**

It would be a back-and-forth sort of careening process, but it should work. A lot depends on how EXACTLY the magic system works, so the details would be up in the air. But a ship built of the special clay (reinforced, perhaps) could contain a crew and supplies needed to survive in space. Although I can't entirely follow the system, I think the rotational system of a smaller internal one of these solar systems (like a Jupiter system within the Sol system) could be used as the core of a generator (providing the rotation of a motor) to power internal systems. As long as your ship were moving, it would be constantly accelerating and you would use this acceleration to simulate gravity for the crew. When it decided to stop, it could orbit the "sun" like the wheel of a space station, using [centrifugal force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrifugal_force)

Answer (score 0):

**Artificial Gravity in Space**

The ability to be able to create gravity would be useful once people are in space. Instead of making a sphere out of the clay, they could cover the ground of a rocket or space station with this clay. Once they arrive in space, they could use this clay floor to create a sort of artificial gravity.

This is useful because there are many side effects of staying in a place with no gravity; artificial gravity would solve all of these. Astronauts, once in space, have to constantly exercise because the lack of gravity weakens muscles and bones. They also have a hard time adjusting, because having no sense of up and down confuses the body.

So, creating artificial gravity for spaceships and space stations would allow long stays in space without significant side effects due to lack of gravity.

> or will be enhanced by material from moons and asteroids

So there are useful materials on moons and asteroids. Using artificial gravity (clay-covered roads if the material is above ground, clay-floored mines if underground) so that the gravity on the moon or asteroids would match that of Earth would make collecting these materials easier.

**Generating Electricity**

There is already a way to generate electricity using gravity (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_battery). According to this article, there is a technology called Lifted Weight Storage(LWS) that uses gravity to generate power. Basically, an object is lifted high up (several hundred meters), and energy is collected when the object falls.

This process could be made much easier and faster when there is gravity magic. Attach some clay on both sides (the floor and the ceiling). If people can control the gravitational force of these clay, they can use the upper clay for lifting, and the lower clay plus the original Earth gravity for dropping. This will generate more energy, and the object won't have to be lifted hundreds of meters high (since it will fall at a greater speed).

You can also take a horizontal approach; attach clay on two sides (left and right), and constantly adjust the gravitational forces of them to move a certain object (some kind of metal, I'm assuming). The kinetic energy of this object could be converted to electricity.

**Magnets**

If the gravity affects other objects, the clay could be used as magnets, but for all objects -- not only for strong metals. It seems like the user can also change the magnitude of the gravitational force of these clay, so that's a bonus function.

**Understanding Gravity & Simulations**

It would be easier for scientists to understand how gravity affects planets and spaceships because they could easily make simulations. This would make calculations for space travel easier.

Comment: Hope this helps :) I'm not a professional, so some information could be inaccurate.